# Setting up virtual cam with v4l2loopback

Tags: webcam

I'm new here and I'm relatively new to Linux so sorry if I'm making a lot of mistakes

So I'm trying to set up a virtual cam with v4l2loopback but the only thing I could find was people who put their whole screen in the cam, idk how to explain but I don't want the virtualcam to be my screen, I want it to be focused on a program so that people only see the content of said program

I got the cam to work by writing this :

```
ffmpeg -f x11grab -r 15 -s 1440x900 -i :0.0+0,0 -vcodec rawvideo -pix_fmt yuv420p -threads 0 -f v4l2 /dev/video0
```

but again, it shows my whole screen.
Sorry for explaining badly, I'm new to Linux and english isn't my primary language. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can stream just a window with gstreamer like this (I'm using /dev/video2):

```
$ gst-launch-1.0 ximagesrc xid=0x06800005 ! videoconvert ! v4l2sink device=/dev/video2
```

In order to get the `xid` of the window you can run:

```
$ wmctrl -l
```

Currently `gst-launch-1.0` is in package `gstreamer1.0-tools` and `wmctrl` in package `wmctrl`.